# Z3_MEMOUT_FAIL assertion failure in Z3's C++ API solver check?

Tags: exception, z3

I am getting a Z3_MEMOUT_FAIL as the assertion failure when I call solver.check(). What does this actually mean? Is it simply that Z3 function ran out of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that exception means that the solver ran out of memory.

Comment: How can I change the amount of memory given to solver.check() function?

Comment: That depends on your system. By default Z3 does not limit the amount of memory to be used.